# UIMODE is not recognised when installing SQL Express Server

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-express

I am at a loss after reading and searching a lot regarding this subject.

I am trying to create a Configuration file for a silent installation of `SQL Server Express 2008`. However, there is an error when I use the `UIMODE` switch as many suggest with the command

```
SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /UIMODE=Normal

Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2008 Setup 10.00.1601.01
```

I've tried this with Express with Tools, and normal express file. I've also tried doing it with the extracted files (with Setup.exe) and the original file from Microsoft.

The error is in the screenshot. I've searched everywhere and nobody seems to have this error? Can anyone help me out?

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: In the end, i used `SQLEXPRWT_X86` (SQL Server 2008 Express with Tools). I ran the Setup normally and even though this was the Express edition, I still get the UI to the point where it says "Ready to Install" and showed me a created Configuration file.